# Laravel 5.8 send parameters to authorize method FormRequest Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-authorization

I have `update` and `store` method like this

```
public function update(ContactRequest $request)
{
   if (Auth::user()->can('edit_contact'))
         $request->update();
   else 
        return $this->accessDenied();
}
public function store(ContactRequest $request)
{
   if (Auth::user()->can('add_contact'))
         $request->store();
   else 
        return $this->accessDenied();
}
```

and `authorize` in `FormRequest` class

```
public function authorize()
{
    return   \Gate::allows('test', $this->route('contact'));
}
```

I want to pass permission name to `authorize` method like this:

```
public function authorize($permissionName)
{
    if (Auth::user()->can($permissionName))
          return   \Gate::allows('test', $this->route('contact'));
}
```

and in controller like this

```
public function update(ContactRequest $request)
{
     $request->update('edit_contact');
}
public function store(ContactRequest $request)
{
     $request->store('add_contact');
}
```

Comment: Where `$permissionName` comes from?

Comment: from `store` and `update` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Change your authorization method to this:

   ```php
   public function authorize()
   {
       return $this->user()->can(
               $this->route()->getActionMethod() === 'store'
                   ? 'add_contact'
                   : 'edit_contact'
           )
           && \Gate::allows('test', $this->route('contact'));
   }
   ```
2. Make your `authorize` method of request return `true` and check authorization by defining another gate an call it on your controller:

   ```php
   public function authorize()
   {
       return true;
   }
   ```

   ```php
   Gate::define('modify_contact', function ($user, $permissionName) {
       return $user->can($permissionName)
           && $user->can('test', $request->route('contact'));
   });
   ```

   ```php
   public function update(ContactRequest $request)
   {
        Gate::authorize('modify_contact', 'edit_contact');
        //...
   }
   public function store(ContactRequest $request)
   {
        Gate::authorize('modify_contact', 'add_contact');
        //...
   }
   ```
3. Define and use [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#creating-policies) the same way and pass your arguments to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of passing argument to authorize method of form request, but you can do the implementation this way:

```
public function authorize()
{
    $method = Request::method();

    if($method == 'post') {
        $permission = 'add_contact';
    } elseif($method == 'put') {
        $permission = 'edit_contact';
    }

    if (Auth::user()->can($permission))
        return \Gate::allows('test', $this->route('contact'));
}
```

If you are using laravel's default post, put routes then this will help you out.

Comment: It's work correctly but I think that is not clear code and exists better way

Answer (score 0):

It is better to make two different Requests for store and update, anyway you need to check some values depended on action.
So you can user default laravel's policy approach for Resource controllers and not use `Request::authorize` for authorization logic.
[Laravel policy controller helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-controller-helpers)

Comment: I won't suggest creating separate from request for store and update, this way you ll be ending up updating same rules/messages in two different classes.